# Blank email attachment received

Tags: php, email

I'm sending email with resume in either docx or pdf format. I manage to upload the file in the server and sent the email out. However when I receive, I'm unable to download the attachment. yet it downloads by itself after showing the warning. And when i open it ,turns out to be blank ! what might be the cause? Below are the related files.Thanks.

sendmail.php

```
<?php
session_start();
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 $password = $_SESSION['password'];

//Check do we have username and password
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE><?php echo $row_RecWebConfig['config_title']; ?> - <?php echo $row_RecContent['CntName']; ?></TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="Description" content="<?php echo $row_RecContent['Description']; ?>">
<meta name="KeyWords" content="<?php echo $row_RecContent['Keywords']; ?>">
<link REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="favicon.ico">
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css 
href="content.css"><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css 
href="cart.css">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="jquery-1.6.X.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<!--DROP DOWN MENU START--><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css 
href="style.css"><!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <link href="ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <![endif]--><!--DROP DOWN MENU END--><!--CSS BUTTONS START--><LINK 
rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="css3buttons.css"><!--CSS BUTTONS END--><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM --><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM -->
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="jquery.slider.js"></SCRIPT>
<!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM --><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM -->
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25360251-11']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function(){
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </SCRIPT>
<!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM --><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM -->
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="pirobox.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="global.css">
<SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript>
                                        $(function(){ 
                                            $().piroBox({ my_speed: 300, bg_alpha: 0.5, slideShow: true, slideSpeed: 3 });
                                        })
                                    </SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="category.css"><!--[if lt IE 8]><link href="category-ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
<!--<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="style-gallery.css">
-->
<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.7600.16722"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV class=global_wrap>
<?php  include('header.php'); ?>
<DIV class=clear></DIV>
<?php include('banner.php'); ?>
<DIV class=clear></DIV>
<DIV id=wrapper_content>
<DIV id=top_container></DIV>
<DIV id=body_container_2>
<DIV id=quickfacts class=auto_margin>
<DIV id=whitecontainer style="padding-left:30px; padding-right:35px">
<h1></h1></DIV></DIV>
<?php 
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 80000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
   /* echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";*/
   /* if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {*/


    $file=uniqid('')."_".$_FILES["file"]["name"];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" .$file);


      /*echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      echo "<span style='padding-left:30px;'>File Attached:".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."</span><br><br>";*/
      echo"<span style='padding-left:30px;'>Fill up below form to send out email</span><br>";

  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}

 ?> 

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<Body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="mail.php">

<table width="auto" border="0" align="center">
<tr><td><div align="right">File Attached:</div></td><td>
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]; ?>">
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Name:</div></td>
<td><input name="nume" type="text" id="nume">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Surname:</div></td>
<td><input name="prenume" type="text" id="prenume"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">*Sender E- mail: </div></td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Aplication for : </div></td>
<td><input name="post" type="text" id="post"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
<span style='padding-left:30px;'><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Next &gt;&gt;&gt;"></span>
</p>
</form>

</DIV><!--end body_container"-->
<DIV id=bottom_container2></DIV>
<DIV class=clear></DIV></DIV><!--end wrapper_content--></DIV><!--end global_wrap-->
<?php include('footer.php'); ?></BODY></HTML>
```

mail.php

```
<?php
session_start();
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 $password = $_SESSION['password'];

//Check do we have username and password
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE><?php echo $row_RecWebConfig['config_title']; ?> - <?php echo $row_RecContent['CntName']; ?></TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="Description" content="<?php echo $row_RecContent['Description']; ?>">
<meta name="KeyWords" content="<?php echo $row_RecContent['Keywords']; ?>">
<link REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="favicon.ico">
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css 
href="content.css"><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css 
href="cart.css">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="jquery-1.6.X.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<!--DROP DOWN MENU START--><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css 
href="style.css"><!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <link href="ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <![endif]--><!--DROP DOWN MENU END--><!--CSS BUTTONS START--><LINK 
rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="css3buttons.css"><!--CSS BUTTONS END--><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM --><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM -->
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="jquery.slider.js"></SCRIPT>
<!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM --><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM -->
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25360251-11']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function(){
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </SCRIPT>
<!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM --><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM -->
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="pirobox.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="global.css">
<SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript>
                                        $(function(){ 
                                            $().piroBox({ my_speed: 300, bg_alpha: 0.5, slideShow: true, slideSpeed: 3 });
                                        })
                                    </SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="category.css"><!--[if lt IE 8]><link href="category-ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
<!--<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="style-gallery.css">
-->
<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.7600.16722"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV class=global_wrap>
<?php  include('header.php'); ?>
<DIV class=clear></DIV>
<?php include('banner.php'); ?>
<DIV class=clear></DIV>
<DIV id=wrapper_content>
<DIV id=top_container></DIV>
<DIV id=body_container_2>
<DIV id=quickfacts class=auto_margin>
<DIV id=whitecontainer style="padding-left:30px; padding-right:35px">
<h1></h1></DIV></DIV>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
{   

if(empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $email=NULL;
    echo"<span style='padding-left:30px;'>Your email must not be empty!Please go back and fill up.</span><br>";
    echo '<span style="padding-left:30px;"><INPUT Type="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></span>';
}
else
{

//to be successfull in useing this code you need to create a directory called upload
//on you ftp create a directory upload in wich copy the content of the zip file

//$filleant takes the value of the picture that was jut uploaded with the unique name to the ftp in the www.yourname.com/upload/upload
$fileatt = "www.example.com/upload/".$_POST["name"]; // Path to the file                  
$fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; // File Type 
//here i made the file that will be sent as attachment to have the name "CV_name_surname.doc" you can make it what format you like,
//i needed the doc format... and i'll modify this code to accept just doc file later...i'm really tired right now :D
$fileatt_name = "CV_".$_POST['nume']."_".$_POST['prenume'].".doc"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment 

//$email_from is the variable that gets the value, of the From: field that will appear in your received mail 
$email_from = $_POST['nume']." ".$_POST['prenume']; // Who the email is from 

//Here you define the subject of you message
$email_subject = "CV."; // The Subject of the email 

//here you define the body of the message, the message itself
//you can modify the "post" textfield in sendmail.php to a textarea....
$email_message = $_POST['post']; // Message that the email has in it 

//here you enter the e-mail address to wich you want the message to be sent
$email_to = "kalaivaninair@ymail.com"; // Who the email is too 

//adds the e-mail address of the sender
$headers = "From: ".$_POST['email']; 

$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . 
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . 
            " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
                "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
                "Content-Type:text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . 
               "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
$email_message . "\n\n"; 



/********************************************** First File ********************************************/ 

//$filleant takes the value of the picture that was jut uploaded with the unique name to the ftp in the www.yourname.com/upload/upload
$fileatt = "www.pmw-industries.com/upload/".$_POST["name"]; // Path to the file                  

$fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; // File Type 

//here i made the file that will be sent as attachment to have the name "CV_name_surname.doc" you can make it what format you like,
//i needed the doc format... and i'll modify this code to accept just doc file later...i'm really tired right now :D
$fileatt_name = "CV".$_POST['nume']."_".$_POST['prenume'].".docx"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment 

$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb'); 
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt)); 
fclose($file); 

$output = ob_get_flush();
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
                  "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" . 
                  " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" . 
                  "Content-Disposition: attachment;" . 
                 " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" . 
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
                 $data . "\n\n" . 
                  "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; 
unset($data); 
unset($file); 
unset($fileatt);
unset($fileatt_type); 
unset($fileatt_name); 

/********************************************** End of File Config ********************************************/ 

// To add more files just copy the file section again, but make sure they are all one after the other! If they are not it will not work! 

$ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
if($ok) { 
echo "<span style='padding-left:30px;'><font face=verdana size=2>The email was successfully sent!</font></span>"; 
} else { 
die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!"); 
} }}
?>


</DIV><!--end body_container"-->
<DIV id=bottom_container2></DIV>
<DIV class=clear></DIV></DIV><!--end wrapper_content--></DIV><!--end global_wrap-->
<?php include('footer.php'); ?></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Use a library like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer to ease up your job.

Comment: Here you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail
See the accepted answer ;)

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to make the absolute path of the file. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/upload/' .$file`.

Answer (score 0):

try edited

```php
<?php
session_start();
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 $password = $_SESSION['password'];

//Check do we have username and password
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE><?php echo $row_RecWebConfig['config_title']; ?> - <?php echo $row_RecContent['CntName']; ?></TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="Description" content="<?php echo $row_RecContent['Description']; ?>">
<meta name="KeyWords" content="<?php echo $row_RecContent['Keywords']; ?>">
<link REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="favicon.ico">
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css
href="content.css"><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css
href="cart.css">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="jquery-1.6.X.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<!--DROP DOWN MENU START--><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css
href="style.css"><!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <link href="ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <![endif]--><!--DROP DOWN MENU END--><!--CSS BUTTONS START--><LINK
rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="css3buttons.css"><!--CSS BUTTONS END--><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM --><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM -->
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="jquery.slider.js"></SCRIPT>
<!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM --><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM -->
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25360251-11']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function(){
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </SCRIPT>
<!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM --><!-- THE LEAD CODER AT MOBIPOT KEATLIANG2005[AT]GMAIL[DOT]COM -->
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="pirobox.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="global.css">
<SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript>
                                        $(function(){
                                            $().piroBox({ my_speed: 300, bg_alpha: 0.5, slideShow: true, slideSpeed: 3 });
                                        })
                                    </SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="category.css"><!--[if lt IE 8]><link href="category-ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
<!--<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="style-gallery.css">
-->
<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.7600.16722"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV class=global_wrap>
<?php  include('header.php'); ?>
<DIV class=clear></DIV>
<?php include('banner.php'); ?>
<DIV class=clear></DIV>
<DIV id=wrapper_content>
<DIV id=top_container></DIV>
<DIV id=body_container_2>
<DIV id=quickfacts class=auto_margin>
<DIV id=whitecontainer style="padding-left:30px; padding-right:35px">
<h1></h1></DIV></DIV>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
{

if(empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $email=NULL;
    echo"<span style='padding-left:30px;'>Your email must not be empty!Please go back and fill up.</span><br>";
    echo '<span style="padding-left:30px;"><INPUT Type="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></span>';
}
else
{

//to be successfull in useing this code you need to create a directory called upload
//on you ftp create a directory upload in wich copy the content of the zip file

//$filleant takes the value of the picture that was jut uploaded with the unique name to the ftp in the www.yourname.com/upload/upload
$fileatt = "www.pmw-industries.com/upload/".$_POST["name"]; // Path to the file
$fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; // File Type
//here i made the file that will be sent as attachment to have the name "CV_name_surname.doc" you can make it what format you like,
//i needed the doc format... and i'll modify this code to accept just doc file later...i'm really tired right now :D
$fileatt_name = "CV_".$_POST['nume']."_".$_POST['prenume'].".doc"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment

//$email_from is the variable that gets the value, of the From: field that will appear in your received mail
$email_from = $_POST['nume']." ".$_POST['prenume']; // Who the email is from

//Here you define the subject of you message
$email_subject = "CV."; // The Subject of the email

//here you define the body of the message, the message itself
//you can modify the "post" textfield in sendmail.php to a textarea....
$email_message = $_POST['post']; // Message that the email has in it

//here you enter the e-mail address to wich you want the message to be sent
$email_to = "kalaivaninair@ymail.com"; // Who the email is too

//adds the e-mail address of the sender
$headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'];

$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n" .
                "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n" .
                "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n" .
               "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n" .
$email_message . "\r\n\r\n";



/********************************************** First File ********************************************/

//$filleant takes the value of the picture that was jut uploaded with the unique name to the ftp in the www.yourname.com/upload/upload
$fileatt = "www.pmw-industries.com/upload/".$_POST["name"]; // Path to the file

$fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; // File Type

//here i made the file that will be sent as attachment to have the name "CV_name_surname.doc" you can make it what format you like,
//i needed the doc format... and i'll modify this code to accept just doc file later...i'm really tired right now :D
$fileatt_name = "CV".$_POST['nume']."_".$_POST['prenume'].".docx"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment

$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);

$output = ob_get_flush();
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n" .
                  "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type}; name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\r\n" .
                  "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\r\n" .
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n" .
                 $data . "\r\n\r\n" .
                  "--{$mime_boundary}--\r\n";
unset($data);
unset($file);
unset($fileatt);
unset($fileatt_type);
unset($fileatt_name);

/********************************************** End of File Config ********************************************/

// To add more files just copy the file section again, but make sure they are all one after the other! If they are not it will not work!

$ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
if($ok) {
echo "<span style='padding-left:30px;'><font face=verdana size=2>The email was successfully sent!</font></span>";
} else {
die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!");
} }}
?>


</DIV><!--end body_container"-->
<DIV id=bottom_container2></DIV>
<DIV class=clear></DIV></DIV><!--end wrapper_content--></DIV><!--end global_wrap-->
<?php include('footer.php'); ?></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Deadooshka,really appreciate that,but still the same.The file has been successfully uploaded into the server but when I retrieve it in the email it's blank.I guess the error occurs during fetching  the file from the server.

Comment: @Lana I forgot that the end boundary must be with hyphens at the start and at the end. Also you have two same lines with $fileatt, leave needed one. I edited the above. I got the raw mail with it and it's seems valid.

Comment: @Lana check if this path is valid `"www.pmw-industries.com/upload/".$_POST["name"];`. Try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/upload/' .$_POST["name"];` instead.